# Comparing a table to itself in a query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run a SQL query that will provide details of repeated records

The Query is:

```
 USE DUBS
 SELECT a.Full_Name, a.status AS STAT1, b.status AS STAT2, a.PAID AS ID1, b.PAID AS ID2 
 from samples a, samples b 
 where a.Full_Name = b.Full_Name and a.status <>    b.status and a.PAID <> b.PAID and B.status <> a.status
```

But the results:

```
 Full_Name           STAT1      STAT2         ID1                        ID2
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AAta01-OCT-1967    Active     Inactive       3100045433                40933
 AAta01-OCT-1967    Inactive    Active          40933                   3100045433
```

I like them to be like this

```
 Full_Name          STAT1   STAT2       ID1         ID2
 AAta01-OCT-1967    Active  Inactive    3100045433  40933
```

Can any help what am I missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got is a filtered version of what's called a cross join, or Cartesian product.

Let's suppose you have two records in `samples`.  Let's call them `x` and `y`.

You're joining `samples` to itself, so if you had two records in `samples`, you'd end up with four (unfiltered) pairs of rows:

```
x joined with x
x joined with y
y joined with x
y joined with y
```

You are filtering out the cases where the record from `a` is identical to the record from `b`.  So you wind up with these two pairs:

```
x joined with y
y joined with x
```

That explains what you're seeing.

The easiest, fastest way to get just one record for every possible pairing?  Use a `<` operator rather than a `<>` for the IDs:

```
SELECT a.Full_Name
     , a.status AS STAT1
     , b.status AS STAT2
     , a.PAID AS ID1
     , b.PAID AS ID2 
from   samples a, samples b 
where  a.Full_Name = b.Full_Name 
  and  a.status <> b.status 
  and  a.PAID < b.PAID
```

This will further filter your records so you only get one record for each pairing.

Comment: please don't join tables in the WHERE clause

Comment: @t-clausen.dk  Agreed; I should have corrected that rather than copying it from the question.